# Count whitespace in node XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, sum, counting

> I need the help with counting whitespace in items gml:pos and gml:posList and >summarize number of whitespace and then div 2. I need the result number of all whitespece in gml:pos and gml:posList/2
>   I use XSLT 1.0
>
> Thank you for your help

Here is my attempt

```
    <xsl:template match="/" name="count">
  <xsl:for-each select="//gml:posList|//gml:pos">
  <xsl:value-of select="sum(string-length(.)-string-length(translate(.,' ','')))"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

Here is input:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <AIXMBasicMessage
 xmlns="http://www.aixm.aero/schema/5.1/message"
 xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2"
 xmlns:aixm="http://www.aixm.aero/schema/5.1"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:gts="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gts"
 xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco"
xmlns:adr="http://www.aixm.aero/schema/5.1/extensions/EUR/ADR"
 xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" gml:id="uniqueId"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.aixm.aero/schema/5.1/message
 http://www.aixm.aero/schema/5.1/message/AIXM_BasicMessage.xsd
 http://www.aixm.aero/schema/5.1/extensions/EUR/ADR
 http://www.aixm.aero/schema/5.1/extensions/EUR/ADR18.5/ADR_Features.xsd">
 <hasMember>        <aixm:Airspace
 xmlns="http://www.aixm.aero/schema/5.1/message"
 gml:id="uuid.b6950093-ae6d-4ef4-b7bf-c30074810e72">            <gml:identifier
 codeSpace="urn:uuid:">b6950093-ae6d-4ef4-b7bf-c30074810e72</gml:identifier>
            <gml:boundedBy xsi:nil="true"/>             <aixm:timeSlice owns="false">
                <aixm:AirspaceTimeSlice gml:id="uuid.d3c353b4-0bbc-4035-91df-24b342c56497">
                    <gml:validTime xlink:type="simple" owns="false">
                        <gml:TimePeriod gml:id="uuid.d3065abe-6c92-4da0-8455-e498b70f48d1" frame="#ISO-8601">
                            <gml:beginPosition frame="#ISO-8601">2015-06-25T00:00:00Z</gml:beginPosition>
                            <gml:endPosition indeterminatePosition="unknown" frame="#ISO-8601"/>
                        </gml:TimePeriod>
                    </gml:validTime>
                    <aixm:interpretation>BASELINE</aixm:interpretation>
                    <aixm:sequenceNumber>2</aixm:sequenceNumber>
                    <aixm:correctionNumber>0</aixm:correctionNumber>
                    <aixm:featureLifetime xlink:type="simple" owns="false">
                        <gml:TimePeriod gml:id="uuid.738e81ce-7c9b-471f-bf49-2d30efb712d5" frame="#ISO-8601">
                            <gml:beginPosition frame="#ISO-8601">2007-08-02T00:00:00Z</gml:beginPosition>
                            <gml:endPosition indeterminatePosition="unknown" frame="#ISO-8601"/>
                        </gml:TimePeriod>
                    </aixm:featureLifetime>
                    <aixm:type>D_OTHER</aixm:type>
                    <aixm:designator>EDFL</aixm:designator>
                    <aixm:name>FGDF</aixm:name>
                    <aixm:designatorICAO>NO</aixm:designatorICAO>
                    <aixm:controlType>CIVIL</aixm:controlType>
                    <aixm:geometryComponent>
                        <aixm:AirspaceGeometryComponent gml:id="uuid.ab5ac3fb-bf03-4128-86df-35061368215c">
                            <aixm:theAirspaceVolume>
                                <aixm:AirspaceVolume gml:id="uuid.944b396c-8f92-45d3-a14c-1d02d2d39c87">
                                    <aixm:upperLimit uom="FL">40</aixm:upperLimit>
                                    <aixm:upperLimitReference>STD</aixm:upperLimitReference>
                                    <aixm:lowerLimit uom="FT">3510</aixm:lowerLimit>
                                    <aixm:lowerLimitReference>MSL</aixm:lowerLimitReference>
                                    <aixm:horizontalProjection>
                                        <aixm:Surface xsi:type="aixm:ElevatedSurfaceType" gml:id="uuid.17a135e0-8e6d-4086-aae1-8ee552b4cd00">
                                            <gml:patches>
                                                <gml:PolygonPatch interpolation="planar">
                                                    <gml:exterior>
                                                        <gml:Ring>
                                                            <gml:curveMember xlink:type="simple" owns="false">
                                                                <gml:Curve xsi:type="aixm:CurveType" srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326"
 gml:id="uuid.5faf7d1e-e0f6-484c-a4cc-965341d5a780">
                                                                    <gml:segments>
                                                                        <gml:ArcByCenterPoint interpolation="circularArcCenterPointWithRadius" numArc="1"
 numDerivativesAtStart="0" numDerivativesAtEnd="0"
 numDerivativeInterior="0">
                                                                            <gml:pos>51.165 4.181289</gml:pos>
                                                                            <gml:radius uom="[nmi_i]">40.0</gml:radius>
                                                                            <gml:startAngle uom="deg">121.451258936276643</gml:startAngle>
                                                                            <gml:endAngle uom="deg">134.6012057585252537</gml:endAngle>
                                                                        </gml:ArcByCenterPoint>
                                                                        <gml:GeodesicString interpolation="geodesic" numDerivativesAtStart="0" numDerivativesAtEnd="0"
 numDerivativeInterior="0">
                                                                            <gml:posList>50.69389 4.9312417 50.7122806 4.86556 50.7129444 4.9175</gml:posList>
                                                                        </gml:GeodesicString>
                                                                        <gml:ArcByCenterPoint interpolation="circularArcCenterPointWithRadius" numArc="1"
 numDerivativesAtStart="0" numDerivativesAtEnd="0"
 numDerivativeInterior="0">
                                                                            <gml:pos>50.78167 4.95778</gml:pos>
                                                                            <gml:radius uom="[nmi_i]">1.7</gml:radius>
                                                                            <gml:startAngle uom="deg">296.6484324915256</gml:startAngle>
                                                                            <gml:endAngle uom="deg">357.5095314492478</gml:endAngle>
                                                                        </gml:ArcByCenterPoint>
                                                                        <gml:GeodesicString interpolation="geodesic" numDerivativesAtStart="0" numDerivativesAtEnd="0"
> numDerivativeInterior="0">
                                                                            <gml:posList>50.81 4.95583 50.1281333 5.08472</gml:posList>
                                                                        </gml:GeodesicString>
                                                                    </gml:segments>
                                                                </gml:Curve>
                                                            </gml:curveMember>
                                                        </gml:Ring>
                                                    </gml:exterior>
                                                </gml:PolygonPatch>
                                            </gml:patches>
                                        </aixm:Surface>
                                    </aixm:horizontalProjection>
                            </aixm:AirspaceVolume>
                            </aixm:theAirspaceVolume>
                        </aixm:AirspaceGeometryComponent>
                    </aixm:geometryComponent>
                </aixm:AirspaceTimeSlice>           </aixm:timeSlice>       </aixm:Airspace>    </hasMember>    </AIXMBasicMessage>
```

Comment: What XSLT have you attempted so far?

Comment: Already I edited my XSLT

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34874446/sum-number-of-div-in-the-html-table-xslt

Comment: I think is different I asked the how many whitespaces are in the node not how many nodes are in the xml

Comment: Can you help with this please?

Comment: "*Can you help with this please?*" I already did that in your other question. I gave you a method to count the spaces **and** another method that doesn't require counting them. -- BTW, you cannot count spaces in `gml:pos` and `gml:posList` alike, because `gml:pos` has one space per point, while `gml:posList` has two spaces per point minus one.

Comment: Please take care of your previous questions. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34874446/1987598) have answers that you have not accepted yet. You have not bothered to give enough information in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34353134/1987598) - please edit it. In general, please **learn from your mistakes** and heed the advice that is given to you when you ask new questions. More info: [how does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Thanks you I am sorry for my mistakes

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do, is concatenate all nodes together in a single variable, like so:

```
<xsl:variable name="allPoints">
   <xsl:for-each select="//gml:posList|//gml:pos">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()" />
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

You can then apply your current expression to this variable, to get the total number of whitespaces

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(string-length($allPoints)-string-length(translate($allPoints,' ','')))"/>
```

Try this XSLT as an example

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"  xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:call-template name="count" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="count">
  <xsl:variable name="allPoints">
    <xsl:for-each select="//gml:posList|//gml:pos">
      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()" />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:value-of select="sum(string-length($allPoints)-string-length(translate($allPoints,' ','')))"/>
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @SimonaFrankova It is really important that you learn how to accept an answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) (this is a link that you can click). It would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`sum()` is for a node-set, not for summing scalar values.  For example, if you had a group of nodes and you wanted to add up their (numeric) contents , you'd use `sum()`.  Your template should just be adjusted to this:

```
<xsl:template match="/" >
  <xsl:for-each select="//gml:pos | //gml:posList">
    <!--<xsl:value-of select="local-name()" /> with content <xsl:value-of select="." /> has --> 
    <xsl:value-of select="string-length(.) - string-length(translate(.,' ',''))"/> <!-- whitespace characters  -->
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Here is result :  1115151311333393333533333311151151591913151117151317133313192313151311715111711113131393159115191471891515131553919511511151515141321515111793311735313515391131143133353335371519513335123111111934133335139151331111159331311 and.......

Comment: Yes - because it's just outputing the numbers. Try uncommenting the commented nodes to see what nodes are giving you what counts.